# Unable to connect iPad with Lenovo ThinkPad Nano X1 through USB-C SuperSpeed/Thunderbolt 3 cables

Tags: usb, windows-11, thinkpad, usb-c, ipad

I have an [iPad Pro 11" (2021)](https://www.gsmarena.com/apple_ipad_pro_11_(2021)-10865.php) and [Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Nano Gen 1](https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/ThinkPad/ThinkPad_X1_Nano_Gen_1/ThinkPad_X1_Nano_Gen_1_Spec.PDF) laptop with Windows 11 Pro.

I'm trying to connect them with USB-C SuperSpeed cable, but no luck. Windows shows me an error:

> [image: USB device not recognized]

On iPad I see the charging icon, so it seems that everything OK with power part:

> [image: iPad is changing]

After that laptop even can't be restarted, simply stuck somewhere after restarting animated icon disappeared. So I have to only make hard reset by holding the power button for several seconds.

Connection with a thin USB-C cable works well (but slow) only if I didn't connect other cables (after system restart) that led to an error message. Here's the photo of cables:

> [image: USB-C cables]

Top one (connected to laptop on photo) works fine, others - leads to described problems.

How I can find the root of issue preventing me to pair my devices on high speed?

Same SS cable works well with the same iPad on Windows 10 desktop machine.

Same SS cable works well with Samsung S22 phone on the same laptop.

I found the cable marked "Thunderbolt 3" that comes with official Lenovo dock-station:

> [image: Thunderbolt 3]

iPad is charging, but I'm still facing with "USB device not recognized" error in Windows.

At the same time I can successfully connect iPad through the [dock-station](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/options/thinkpad_thunderbolt3_ug_en_201812.pdf)'s port 3 (Thunderbolt 3) to my laptop with ANY cable mentioned before (except TB3 since it's used to connect dock-station it self):

> [image: Connection via dock-station Thunderbolt 3]

I've made attempt #6 described [here](https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-fix-unknown-usb-device-port-reset-failed-error-windows-11/):

> 6. Reinstall All the USB Controllers
>    If updating the driver was not helpful, you can try reinstalling all the devices under the Universal Serial Bus controllers. To do this, follow the below steps:
>
> In the Device Manager, expand the Universal Serial Bus controllers node.
> Right-click on the problematic device and choose Uninstall device.
> Next, restart your computer and plug in the USB device again.

After that I connected thick white cable and it's work! I was able to transfer files to iPad via iTunes app and measure the speed ~56 Mbytes/sec. On thin cable the speed was ~17Mbytes/sec. Connection with a gray SS cable broke further possibility to pair device. Even "Reinstall All the USB Controllers" doesn't work anymore.

Could there be some stray hardware(?) bug? How can this be detected more precisely?

Recently my system got update for Thunderbolt driver on my Lenovo to version 1.41.1379.0:

> [image: Thunderbolt driver updated]

After that I was able to successfully do transfer data to iPad using all of the cables noted above. But on the next round I got the same error "USB device not recognized", and I can't use them anymore.

I really don't understand what is happening here and what next step I should do to find the reason of these fails.

Comment: Your laptop has Thunderbolt 4 (USB 4) ports.  The cables you are using are not TB4 cables. I am shocked either of those cables actually work.  A proper TB4 cable (say the one sold by Apple) should resolve your issue. The fact the cables works on another machine is immaterial, your laptop, has different hardware

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not quite sure, but IIRC same devices work well even with thick cable before I made an upgrade from Win10 to Win11. Despite your recommendation, that stuck on reboot phase doesn't seem as a normal behavior.

Comment: The error you are receiving is the entire controller crashing due to a hardware error.  That hardware error typically is connected to power.  USB 3.2 Gen 2 and USB 4 (TB4) cables negotiate power between the client and host. If that negotiation cannot happen, you have issues like in your screenshot. **BLUF: USB Type-C cables are NOT actually created equal.  Sometimes they violate the USB Standard.  In other instances, they are just dangerous** Here is some backstory. 
 [Benson Leung](https://fossbytes.com/a-google-engineer-forced-amazon-to-ban-bad-usb-cables-with-his-reviews/)

Comment: @Ramhound thank you for your comments. I will try to get a Thunderbolt cable and check connection again.

Comment: @Ramhound I updated the post because I can connect my phone with the same cable to the same laptop with no issue. How you can explain this?

Comment: Your phone requires less power than your iPad to charge.

Comment: @Ramhound post updated. Should I get this issue with Thunderbolt 3 as well?

Comment: Based on my research there only minor changes between TB3 and TB4, they are also backwards compatible, so you would get TB3 performance instead of TB4, but the cable that you indicated does not work is far less capable then the TB cable.