# How to cleanup the history of USB device in Windows?

Tags: windows, usb, device-manager

In the process of fixing [Unable to connect iPad with Lenovo ThinkPad Nano X1 through USB-C SuperSpeed/Thunderbolt 3 cables](https://superuser.com/q/1804300/362161) I reinstalled OS but preserve all the data and apps, and now I'm looking how to cleanup the USB device connection history in Windows.

E.g. I would like to deleted any information from OS related to the following image:

> [image]

How can I do this? I've tried an answer from [here](https://superuser.com/q/1574914/362161), but still see the same "were migrated from previous OS installation".